# I create the deb files from electron-builder and now I want to upload to a PPA for Ubuntu

Tags: deb

I have the multiple archs in deb. I got the PPA account as https://launchpad.net/p3x-onenote, but now when I use the `dbut`, it says `Not a .changes file`. How can I create a `.changes` file? Is there something that can generate this file from the deb?

Comment: Does this help: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-genchanges.1.html

Comment: The problem is, this is a deb that is generated form Electron Builder and the deb is missing the changes.